# How to restrict jquery function to certain pages?

Tags: jquery

This is an excerpt of my javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('form#search').length > 0) {
        setSearchForm();
    }
});

function setSearchForm() {
    var text=$('form#search input[type=text]');
    if (text.val().length != 0) {
        text.next('input[type=submit]').removeProp('disabled');
    } else {
        text.next('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

My problem is: All of my subpages use this `.js` file but not all subpages do have a `search` form.

So on document ready I check for the existence of a search form and then call `setSearchForm()` only if a search form exists.

I found that this is the only way to prevent `setSearchForm()` from running on every page. Because if there is no search form and the function gets triggered anyway, none of the other functions I have in my `js` file will work anymore.

Is there a more elegant solution to this, e.g. by rewriting the function somehow?

I am fairly new to jQuery, so the solution is probably a simple one!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is setSearchForm() called by an event like click event?

Comment: Yes, there's also an event that calls `setSearchForm()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the two functions in a separate .js file and import it only on pages that have a search form.